# Has anyone yet published a version of rough.js that works with ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Colleagues,

I'd love to use something like the [rough.js graphics library](https://roughjs.com/) in my ggplot applications. It not only looks cool, but can emphasise that some data are preliminary and incomplete.

[image: rough chart example]

The [xkcd package](https://xkcd.r-forge.r-project.org/) does a good job, but this one adds colour and text options.

So, has anyone ported the library across to R as a ggplot add-on?

I'm comfortable with much of R, but I'm not a real programmer, and I know nothing of .js libraries. If I'm asking a silly question, help this newbie understand what's involved in such a task.

Comment: https://github.com/xvrdm/ggrough

Comment: yes looks good ... but just to be clear @ekstroem, this isnt my work ;

Comment: Nono ... but knowing that stuff already exists is step number 1

Comment: Thank you, @user20650.
Very much appreciated!